# Deletion button for each table row in AppleScriptObjC

Tags: macos, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, applescript-objc

I'm trying to achive the button that is placed in every row of an table and deletes that row when pressed in AppleScriptObjC. Same as in Safari, when you look at the download list, there is small X button next to the name of a downloaded file.

I can't make the binding of deletion method `deleteRow_(sender)` in an `app delegate` with deletion button to work. I have `Array Controller` that fills the table. I have binded the button to the method but when clicked nothing happens. I have tried to bind the argument of each button to the unique value from the `data source` and set it's target to the `app delegate` itself but it makes the button transparent and unclickable.

Please help how can I make it work using AppleScriptObjC and bindings.

Comment: Is the tableview view based or cell based?

Comment: The target of the action of the button must be the delegate of the tableview.

Comment: Oh, I didn't specified a delegate for the table. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Willeke, I noticed that there was no delegate specified for the table. Table was bind to an property, `property tableName : missing value` in a delegate but not thru outlet `delegate` of an table.

After specifying a delegate for the table, when I bind the action of an button to the same delegate as table view, everything works like a charm.

Now, when action works the second part of this topic is how to obtain the row index or some other info about which button I have pressed? I tried to fill argument with a value taken from a `dataSource`.  I have binded the button to  the `table cell view` with `objectValue.myValue` as `object key path` and button cell bind to `table controller` with `myValue` of `object key path`. Target of both is bind to same delegate as table. but all this setup gives me an error. This binding is done in the same way I bind all my objects to fill the table.

Comment: If you connect the action of the button, the row can be obtained with `rowForView` of NSTableView. The button is the sender. If you connect the action via bindings, you can use `objectValue` as argument and use this object or find it in the data.